# SpringBoot JPARepository JpaSystemException

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using MS SQL server db and getting 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet'

Entity Class:

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "ABC_Data")

public class WeeklyActualESBDao
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "ESB_Actuals_Data_ID")
    private Integer    actualsId;

    @Column(name = "division")
    private Integer    division;

    @Column(name = "familyTreeLevel")
    private String     familyTreeLevel;

    @Column(name = "departmentCode")
    private Integer    departmentCode;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private Integer    year;

    @Column(name = "period")
    private Integer    period;

    @Column(name = "week_of_period")
    private Integer    weekOfPeriod;

    @Column(name = "net_sales")
    private BigDecimal netSales       = new BigDecimal(0);

    @Column(name = "delivered_gross")
    private BigDecimal deliveredGross = new BigDecimal(0);

    @Column(name = "units")
    private Integer    units;
}
```

Repository class:
public interface PrimaryDepartmentSalesESBRepository
extends JpaRepository<WeeklyActualESBDao, Integer>{}

Datatype of columns in DB..

ESB_Actuals_Data_ID ( bigint autoincrement)
division ( int)
familyTreeLevel ( char 64)
departmentCode( int)
year ( int )
period ( int )
weekOfPeriod( int)
netsales ( numeric 30,10 ) etc

Comment: from what line of code is this exception thrown?

Comment: The following exception comes when I call any native query or findAll() method. Not able to figure out the reason for this exception. Please help regarding this exception.